# is there way to convert object into another class in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

let say I have model

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and his STI brother

```
MasqueradeUser < User
end 

masquerade_user =  MasqueradeUser.find 123
masquerade_user.class
# => MasqueradeUser
```

Ridiculous as it sounds, is possible to convert this object back to parent class `User`

```
masquerade_user.some_magic.class   # => User
```

I know I can override methods like `mode_name`, `is_a?(User)` and other so that MasqueradeUser will return values like `User`

```
MasqueradeUser < User
  def model_name
    'User'
  end
end
```

I was just wondering if there is a way to completely downgrade object to parent class instance

Comment: MasqueradeUser.superclass.name

Comment: Can you use `model_name.superclass.name=="User"` or `model_name.ancestors.include? "User"`. If not, perhaps you shouldn't be using STI.

Comment: thx guys but I don't need to implement that comparison/condition in my code, I need to trick other one other gem that my object is different klass. Exactly the solution in  Yehuda Zargarov answer (I'll accept that, just waiting if anyone knows any native Ruby solution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `becomes` function of `ActiveRecord` - see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes).

Comment: perfect works exactly as I need, but do you know if there any build in ruby solution ?

Comment: As much as I know, this is the only way to do this.

Comment: `become`is deprecated and you should use `becomes` now instead (it's the same thing, just a renaming). See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/becomes . +1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can genericize `ActiveRecord`'s `becomes` method as such:

```
def becomes(klass)
  became = klass.new
  became.instance_variable_set("@attributes", @attributes)
  became
end
```

After all it's just a matter of copying variables into another object that supports them (i.e: it can "become" any class, not just the superclass)

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to convert models then I feel like the [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17724746/7573223) is sufficient.

If you need `becomes` like behavior and you either aren't working with ActiveRecord or do not want to include the `ActiveRecord::Persistence` module then I'd suggest a variation of this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17725174/7573223) which has good intentions, but would suggest following the logic in `becomes` more closely.  Also what happens when your initialization method has required params? Then that answer starts to fall apart.  The source for `becomes` gets around this by passing a block to `initialize`, which may be the best approach for you.

### Source for: [ActiveRecord::Persistence#becomes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes)

```rb
def becomes(klass)
  became = klass.allocate

  became.send(:initialize) do |becoming|
    @attributes.reverse_merge!(becoming.instance_variable_get(:@attributes))
    becoming.instance_variable_set(:@attributes, @attributes)
    becoming.instance_variable_set(:@mutations_from_database, @mutations_from_database ||= nil)
    becoming.instance_variable_set(:@new_record, new_record?)
    becoming.instance_variable_set(:@destroyed, destroyed?)
    becoming.errors.copy!(errors)
  end

  became
end
```

I believe there is value in the use of the [`allocate`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Class/allocate) method here, which allows us to have a method like `becomes` without cluttering up the `initialize` method with multiple responsibilities.

### Proposed manual implementation, without `initialize`

```rb
def becomes(wrapper_class)
  wrapper_class.allocate.tap do |wrapper_instance|
    # your logic here for initializing the wrapper_instance with the calling object's values
    # ex:
    @attributes.reverse_merge!(becoming.instance_variable_get(:@attributes))
    wrapper_instance.instance_variable_set("@attributes", @attributes)
  end
end
```

NOTE: Nothing is stopping you from calling `new` or `send(:initialize)` as seen in the source or answers, but it isn't required.

This approach gives you an instance of the wrapper class with some of the values from the original object on the wrapper instance.  Therefore, this method has the single responsibility to convert classes (without any initialization params) and the initialization method (which may or may not have required params) has the single responsibility of creating an instance from scratch.  The distinction may be insignificant or non-existent in some cases, but in the cases where this distinction is important, you will thank yourself for keeping these responsibilities separated.

This leverages the [`tap`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap) method which does all the work of the first and last lines of the `becomes` source and also gives you a block to work within, that is also found in the source. Just seemed more efficient to me.  The only major difference here is that the block is not being passed to `initialize` with this approach. If you want to do that then use:

### Proposed manual implementation, with `initialize`

```rb
def becomes(wrapper_class)
  # `allocate.send(:initialize)` is equivalent to `new` without callbacks for objects like ActiveRecord::Base.
  wrapper_class.allocate.send(:initialize) do |wrapper_instance|
    # your logic here for initializing the wrapper_instance with the calling object's values
    # ex:
    @attributes.reverse_merge!(becoming.instance_variable_get(:@attributes))
    wrapper_instance.instance_variable_set("@attributes", @attributes)
  end
end
```